# Can anyone provide a proof that a compact set in metric space $(X,d)$ is bounded using..

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

using anyone of the following definitions(and no other concerning compactness):

-$A \subseteq (X, \tau)$ **is compact if for every open cover of A there exists a finite cover.**

**-A compact set in a Hausdorff space is closed.**

**-A closed subset of a compact set is compact.**

**-A compact set in metric space  (X,d) is closed.**

I tried to make something happen. Nothing. Search ME, nothing again.

Comment: Using the first definition, cover $A$ by picking $x\in A$ and then covering $A$ with $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n(x)$, where $B_n(x)$ is the ball of radius $n$ centered at $x$.

Comment: Also, the last three are not definitions of compact.

Comment: I'm yet to see a proof more efficient than Joe's comment.

Comment: Is it just me, or is this very trivial?

Comment: In my notebook like 5 lines are written, thats why i ask

Comment: Trivial is relative. Can you finish Joe's argument there? Just one more line.

Comment: The cover of A will be a ball of finite radius-bounded?

Comment: Yes, you get that the set is covered by a finite amount of balls with same center, so it is in the largest ball

Comment: @Joe, you should upgrade your comment to an answer since the problem is solved, so OP can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in A$.  Cover $A$ with the open cover $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n(x)$ where $B_n(x)$ is a ball of radius $n$ centered at $x$.  Then what does it mean to have a finite subcover?